# How to open Nautilus in a specified directory from the command line?

Tags: nautilus, directory

In Microsoft Windows I'm used to being able to type <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then `C:\Temp`, and that will open up the file explorer in the directory specified. Is there a similar way to navigate to a folder in Ubuntu (16.04)?

Comment: I have a shell alias called `r` which simply runs `nautilus .`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> is the key combination you are looking for.

To open any window just specify the location as shown below in screenshot.

[image]

This method is very quick as it gives suggestions also. When I type `Do` it give suggestion for `Documents` and `Downloads` (see screenshot)

**EDIT**:
**Another useful method to quickly excess file and folders**

Use <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

[image]

This will show you frequently and recently used files and folders. Just type the few starting words of your file/folder and it will show you that file/folder and then hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to open the file/folder.

These two methods will greatly save your time and make you more efficient.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal window or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> for a single command input, and then run this command:

```
nautilus /path/to/folder
```

Note, quotes are required around the path if the path contains spaces.

Answer (score 4):

When I'm using the terminal, deep in a folder tree, I often use the command `nautilus .`

`nautilus` obviously loads nautilus, and the period is shorthand for "the current directory." If you do it without the period, it'll load in `~`.

Comment: Thanks, is a nice tip as well. Although the question is more "how to get from desktop to nautilus folder", this is a "how to get from terminal to nautilus folder". In Windows this corresponds to running 'start .' in cmd.exe